# Can I configure NLog to prune logs after they reach a certain limit?

Tags: .net, nlog

Can NLog be configured to automatically prune/trim a log file after it reaches a certain file size?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think the closest you will achieve will be to use the `archiveAboveSize` attribute to get NLog to archive the log file when it reaches a certain size. By combining this with the `maxArchiveFiles` attribute, you can keep the number of archived files to a minimum (although I think you will always need one archived file otherwise when the current log file gets archived and replaced with a new one, the now-archived file will be deleted and you will lose all of the logging in it).

There is [an example](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/File-target#archive-old-log-files) in the documentation.