# NLog stops logging due to disk space problem

Tags: c#, nlog, diskspace

I have a C# application who logs using the `NLog` library.

Due to a lack of disk space, the logging has stopped. That's ok, but now it seems that, even after disk cleanup, the logging does not start again: the application needs to be restarted for the logging to restart.

Is there a version of the `NLog` library which solves this issue?

Version information: currently I'm working with `NLog.4.6.0`.

Thanks in advance

P.s. seen the importance of this issue, I've also created [an NLog bug report](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/5156) for this issue.

Comment: While this does not resolve your issue with NLog not being able to continue once it hits a disk space limit - It might be worth limiting the size of the log file instead so that you do not hit this problem in the first place - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50501773/how-to-set-nlog-max-file-size

Comment: @Kami: Thanks for your interesting remark. I've upvoted the question and the accepted answer.

Comment: NLog v5.1.4 has been released - https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/5.1.4